# What does "it" in "it wasn't" refer to?

Tags: meaning

In *The Matrix Revolutions* (2003), Trinity and Morpheus meet Oracle, who is sitting on the sofa:

> Oracle: I wish there was an easy way to get through this, but there
> ain't. I'm sorry this had to happen. I'm sorry I couldn't be sitting
> here like you remember me... ...but **it** wasn't meant to be.
>
> Trinity: What happened?
>
> Oracle: I made a choice, and that choice cost me more than I wanted it
> to.

What does "it" in "it wasn't" refer to?

Comment: 'It' refers to Oracle not being able to sit there like they remember him or her.

Comment: @MichaelWokeHarvey Who is "they", "him" or "her" in your comment?

Comment: 'They' are Trinity and Morpheus, and 'him or her' is how I chose refer to Oracle, due to not knowing the gender, if any.

Comment: ***it*** refers to exactly the same thing as ***this*** - something which wasn't supposed to happen *(wasn't meant to **be**)*, but in fact *did* happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"It" refers to the previous hypothetical situation: that the Oracle would be sitting there like Trinity remembered her.